# PHP timezone is not being set by php.ini

Tags: php, timezone

In my php.ini I have `date.timezone = America/Puerto_Rico` but the PHP time is an hour behind. When I look at phpinfo() it says

```
date
date/time support   enabled
"Olson" Timezone Database Version   2008.2
Timezone Database   internal
Default timezone    US/Central

Directive   Local Value Master Value
date.default_latitude   31.7667 31.7667
date.default_longitude  35.2333 35.2333
date.sunrise_zenith 90.583333   90.583333
date.sunset_zenith  90.583333   90.583333
date.timezone   America/Puerto_Rico America/Puerto_Rico`
```

Why does it say the default timezone is US/Central even though it knows that date.timezone is set?

Thanks

Edit: I've looked for ini_set, putenv, and data_defualt_timezone_Set and don't have any of them. This is a server wide problem to.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use " as delimiter:

date.timezone = "America/Puerto_Rico"

And reload apache!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're not over-riding the value in another file. You can set that value in any one of a hundred places.

Comment: I've looked for ini_set, putenv, and data_defualt_timezone_Set and don't have any of them.